# Can't remove the duplicate array value in php

Tags: php

I know that this question has been asked before or may be I couldn't find the question and answer related this entire site. I need some advice for this removal procedure for duplicate value in array. Here is my code:

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($rows as $item) {
 if (!in_array($rows, $newarray)) {  
     $newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName'][]  = $item['city_name'];
 }

$newarray[$item['country_name']]['hotelName'][] = $item['hotel_name'];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newarray);
echo '</pre>';
```

This is my output:

```
Array (
[India] => Array
    (
        [cityName] => Array
            (
                [0] => Gurugram
                [1] => Trivandrum
                [2] => Bengaluru
                [3] => Udaipur
                [4] => Salcette
                [5] => Mumbai
                [6] => New Delhi
                [7] => Chennai
                [8] => Salcette
                [9] => Salcette
                [10] => Bengaluru
                [11] => Chennai
                [12] => New Delhi
                [13] => Udaipur
                [14] => Delhi
                [15] => Jaipur
                [16] => Jaipur
            )
```

As you see there is multiple duplicate value in return value. I need something like this:

```
Array (
[India] => Array
    (
        [cityName] => Array
            (
                [0] => Gurugram
                [1] => Trivandrum
                [2] => Bengaluru
                [3] => Udaipur
                [4] => Mumbai
                [5] => Chennai
                [6] => Salcette
                [7] => Chennai
                [8] => New Delhi
                [9] => Udaipur
                [10] => Delhi
                [11] => Jaipur

            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this will help.

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"red");
print_r(array_unique($a));
?>
```

The result looks like,

```
Array ( [a] => red [b] => green )
```

Here, I'm just giving the simple example. we can able to remove the duplicate value in an array using **array_unique()** PHP function

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in your IF statement. change this:

```
if (!in_array($rows, $newarray)) { 
 $newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName'][]  = $item['city_name'];
}
```

to this:

```
if (!isset($newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName']) || !in_array($item['city_name'], $newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName'])) { 
 $newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName'][]  = $item['city_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use *array_unique* function for that**

```
$newarray = array();

foreach($rows as $item) {
   if (!in_array($rows, $newarray)) {  
       $newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName'][]  = $item['city_name'];
   }

   // because of you array is multidimensional 
   // you can use array_unique function with array_map searching

    $newarray= array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize",$newarray)));

    $newarray[$item['country_name']]['hotelName'][] = $item['hotel_name'];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newarray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change $rows in if to $item['city_name'] and try :

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($rows as $item) {
  if (!in_array($item['city_name'], $newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName'])) {  
     $newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName'][]  = $item['city_name'];
  }

$newarray[$item['country_name']]['hotelName'][] = $item['hotel_name'];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newarray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank you! I had use error_reporting(0); for remove flag.

Answer (score 0):

After fixi
Try this one :)

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($rows as $item) {
 $newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName'][]  = $item['city_name'];
 if(count($newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName']) > 1)
 {
   $temp_array = array_values($newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName']);//get values and assign it in new array 
   $temp_array = array_unique($newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName']);// remove duplicate elements 
   $temp_array = array_filter($newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName']);// remove blank elements from array - must use after merging or unique
   $newarray[$item['country_name']]['cityName'] = $temp_array

}

$newarray[$item['country_name']]['hotelName'][] = $item['hotel_name'];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newarray);
echo '</pre>';
```